TensorFlow does not accept list type for dataset generator
I am building a neural network. I couldn't load all the training data into memory at once, so I am using TensorFlow's tf.data.Dataset.from_generator function to load data incrementally. However, it throws an error saying it does not accept a list of tensors as a type.
TypeError: `output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of 
`tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'> which is not.

The input to my neural network is a list of 151 separate tensors. How can I represent this in the generator? My code is below:
def generator(file_paths, batch_size, files_per_batch, tam, value):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: data_generator(file_paths, batch_size, files_per_batch, tam, value),
        output_signature=(
            [tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, tam), dtype=tf.float32) for _ in range(tam+1)],  # Lista de 151 tensores
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, tam), dtype=tf.float32)  # Rótulos
        )
    )

inputArray = [Input(shape=(tam,)) for _ in range(tam + 1)]

train_dataset = generator(file_paths, batch_size, files_per_batch, tam, False)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1000, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

I tried to use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to feed data into my neural network in batches, since I can't load all the data into memory at once.
However, I encountered an error:
TypeError: output_signature must contain objects that are subclass of tf.TypeSpec but found <class 'list'> which is not.


The error message is clearly stating that the data must be of the correct type. The code provides list whereas the requirement is tf.TypeSpec.

perhaps this will help:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TypeSpec

Yes. I realized that this is the problem. But the input layer of my neural network gets a list of tensors. I'm trying to figure out how to represent this input in the generator. It doesn't allow me to directly put a list. I thought about simply stating 151 tensors, but that would be too much work to write.

I solved the problem using a dictionary instead of a list.
def generator(file_paths, batch_size, files_per_batch, size, value):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: data_generator(file_paths, batch_size, files_per_batch, size, value),
        output_signature=(
            {f"input_{i}": tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, size), dtype=tf.float32) for i in range(size + 1)},  # Inputs
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(batch_size, size), dtype=tf.float32)  # Labels
        )
    )

To achieve this, I adjusted the input layer to:
inputArray = [Input(shape=(size,), name=f"input_{i}") for i in range(size + 1)]

This adjustment ensures that the keys from the generator match the keys expected by the model at the input.
